# How to initialise collections of collections in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I get a `util.List` of instances. each instance has its another collection. I want to initialize all instances of collections.  Here is how do it.

```
Hibernate.initialize(parentList);
```

But when the session is closed. parentList's objects'properties can be retrieved. But its collection's instances's properties cannot be retrieved. The way I initialize is wrong or any other problem is there? or how to initialize all instances.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Hibernate.initialize(parentList);
```

will just initialize objects in the list not association inside the list.

From the docs:

> Note: This only ensures intialization of a proxy object or collection;
>   it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be
>   initialized/materialized.

Edit: As per comment

Say if I had one `Student` Entity and every student Entity has a list of `Course` Entity. Then the student list can be initialized like this :

```
for (Student student : studentList) {
     Hibernate.initialize(student.getCourses());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Then is there a way to initialize them ?

Comment: **Note:-**Direct proxy only initialized. If a proxy of a proxy is needed, again `initialize()` must be called as you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: Can you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392996/does-hibernate-initialize-requires-a-time-delay My problem is , if I add debug point and wait for few seconds only I get my list. else it is not working

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to work, is to keep using lazy-loading and use Value Object design pattern to transfer data from persistent object to value object and conversely.